# Correct Version of JBPM And Drools tool for Eclipse Juno 4.2.1

Tags: eclipse, drools, jbpm

forgive me for asking this question. Which is the correct version of **jbpm** and **drools tool** for **Eclipse Juno 4.2.1**? I am desperate as I have googled it and couldn't find the correct answer. Please help me out here.

Comment: Did you encounter any problems? Which Drools version was that?

Comment: I tried Drools version 6.1.0. It's not working on eclipse. I encountered the same problem with JBoss tools before. That problem was solved when I installed the correct version which is compatible with my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a setup eclipse is to download the demo: based on
documentation at: [JBPM Demo](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html#d0e616).  If you run "ant start.demo" per instructions a version of eclipse will be launched.  You can use this version for your development.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed the following tools into eclipse Luna Java EE version. The drools update site will not let you look at the list of releases. I had to install from the following URL: http://downloads.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.1.0.Final/updatesite/.

The BPMN2 Modeler does let you view a list of available version: http://download.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/updates/luna/. I recently installed the version 1.1.2.

I don't think there is a single answer for the "correct" version; however, the latest is probably the best.